# How to show rows as columns

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I want to return data to show rows as columns for example;

```
ref, description
123, bananas, apples, oranges etc
```

There could be more than one description item.

The list from the table is shown in table rows.

```
ref, description
123, bananas
123, apples
123, oranges
```

Any ideas/code appreciated.

Heres the CTE I've created but am happy to explore other robust solutions.

```
with PivotV as (


SELECT        [CO-PERSON-VULNERABILITY].person_ref [Ref], 
(case 
when [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES].DESCRIPTION = 'Restricted Mobility' then 'RM'
when [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES].DESCRIPTION = 'Progressive or Long Term Illness' then 'PLTI'
when [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES].DESCRIPTION = 'ASB / Injunction Order' then 'AIO'
when [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES].DESCRIPTION = 'Beware possible Drug Paraphernalia' then 'BPDP'
when [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES].DESCRIPTION = '[Can''t] Manage Stairs' then 'CMS'


else NULL end) as [VunDesc]
--,[CO-PERSON-VULNERABILITY].vulnerable_code, [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES].[VULNERABLE-IND], 

FROM            [CO-PERSON-VULNERABILITY] INNER JOIN
                         [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES] ON [CO-PERSON-VULNERABILITY].vulnerable_code = [CO_VULNERABLE-CODES].[VULNERABLE-IND])
```

Comment: Please can you post your data, and what you have tried already

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2016

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, before `SQL Server 2017`(there you can use `STRING_AGG()`) it's not that easy to do what you want.

```
SELECT t1.ref
     , STUFF((
       SELECT ',' + t2.description
         FROM #t as t2
        WHERE t2.ref = t1.ref
        ORDER BY t2.description
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') as description
  FROM #t as t1
 GROUP BY t1.ref
```

Comment: Thanks - Worked great